# Limiting memory usage of writestream

Tags: javascript, node.js, pipe, fs

I have used `fs.createWriteStream` to write the response to a file. While it takes ~20mb for smaller file, once I reached to >1gb file, the memory usage grows to ~150mb. I used `process.memoryUsage()` to check the memory.

Is there any way we can optimize the `createWriteStream` method so that the memory footprint remains low even with file of large size?

Comment: How have you implemented the read/write process?

Comment: I'm reading a file using readStream, and then writing to another file using writestream. Everything works fine, I just want to know how the memory usage can be limited.

Comment: Have you tried to pipe the input to the output, like src.pipe(dest) ?

Comment: Yes. it works. Even with writestream, it's working. My question is with writestream, when I try to write big file, the memory usage increases. Is there any option to limit that? Also, in case of pipe, how do I check the memory usage?